# ¿Como borrar palabras repetidas en una cadena si el número de repetición no es el multiplo indicado? en Python

Tags: python, string

Quisiera que cada 2 "holas" se borren pero no el tercero, es decir los múltiplos de 3 que no se borraran y así consecutivamente.

Tengo esto:

```
p = "hola adios hola adios hola adios hola adios hola adios hola adios"
```

Aplicando el proceso quedara:

```
p= "adios adios hola adios adios hola adios"
```

Es el ejemplo ejemplo mínimo verificable para hacer una funcion

Comment: tiene que ser la palabra o una letra?

Comment: la palabra "hola"

Comment: Trata de poner algún intento de tu código.

Answer (score 1):

Vos sabes cual es la palabra que vas a borrar?. Es siempre la misma?.

Se me ocurre que podrias hacer esto:

- Splitea el String y guardala en un Array.
- Recorre el Array, conta la palabra "hola", y anda guardando en otro array
- concatena los valores y retorna ese String.

Comment: Si me pudieses escribir una funcion lo agardeceria porque no se muy bien de lo que estas hablando, lo siento

Answer (score 0):

Una forma simple es esta manera:

```
p = "hola adios hola adios hola adios hola adios hola adios hola adios"

def borrar_palabras(cadena, busqueda, limite):
    cadena = p.split(" ")
    apariciones = 0
    borrados = []
    nueva = []
    for indice, palabra in enumerate(cadena):
        if palabra == busqueda:
            apariciones += 1
            if apariciones < limite:
                borrados.append(indice)
                print("borrado", palabra)
            elif apariciones == limite:
                print("no borrado", palabra)
                apariciones = 0
        else:
            print("no borrado", palabra)

    for indice, palabra in enumerate(cadena):
        if not indice in borrados:
            nueva.append(palabra)
    return nueva

nueva = borrar_palabras(p, "hola", 3)

// ['adios', 'adios', 'hola', 'adios', 'adios', 'adios', 'hola', 'adios']
```

La función responde a lo solicitado "no eliminar los múltiplos de X número", el problema en cuestión radica en que el patrón esperado NO cumple esa condición.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]